# Is it possible to send push notification through gcm while in offline?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send push notification through GCM while offline?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

Comment: Yes it is possible but you will get notification when you online back :P

Comment: Just to add, if you are offline too long then the notification will be discarded. The default is 4 weeks. Read the helpful link @Touregsys provided.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If the phone is in offline mode, then it has no internet connection.  With no internet connection, it's not connecting to Google's servers to receive the notification.